# What do you get when you add a string to an int in Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking through some of my friends Java and he's currently asleep. I don't have the JDK on my computer, and I've never touched Java in my life. What would be the value of checksum int this expression?

```
int score = 15;
String name = "Me";
String checksum = score + name + "salt";
//do stuff
```

Comment: `String checksum ..`  Are you sure that *"I'm looking through some of my friends Java and he's currently asleep."* doesn't actually mean *"I'm **hacking** my friend's Java while he is asleep"*?

Comment: Funny. I mean exactly that, and you happen to have the same first name as my friend ;)

Comment: Lucky I don't have any software with 'protection'.  In fact, most of mine is open-source. :)  Give my sympathies to your friend, and advise them to find better ones (friends, that is).  ;)

Comment: Hehe. I was just testing the server to see if I could inject HTML in to the High Score listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be '15Mesalt'

It simply adds the integer to the string as the number, no frills, nothing really fancy.

Comment: Okay hm. Thanks. That's what I thought, but the output of the hash function doesn't seem consistent with that. Thank you. I'll have to look elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

The in will be converted to a string, so the value of `checksum` will be `15Mesalt`.

From the [java Language Specification (15.18.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) on string concatenation:

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the int in string. In String concatenation int converted to String.

and result will be

```
15MEsalt
```

Answer (score 0):

Result is `15Mesalt`. Your right variable is `String` so `+` operator contacts to operand.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is syntactically left-associative, no matter whether it is determined by type analysis to represent string concatenation or numeric addition.If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.

So the result of the expression `score + name + "salt"` = "15Mesalt";

Here's another scenario:

`System.out.println("Hello" + 'a' + 7);`
`System.out.println('a' + 7 + "Hello");`

The first output is `Helloa7`,while the second is `104Hello`.In the first statement,both of the two `+` operator represent string concatenation.

But for the second one,since the + operator is syntactically left-associative,so `'a'+7` is evaluated first.And now it triggers the java auto type promotion mechanism,turning `'a'` to its corresponding ASCII value `97` and add it to `7`.So the result is `104`,which is an int value.And then `104 + "Hello"` is evaluated.Since the second operand is a string,the `+` operator represents string conctenation right now.So the result is `104Hello`.